# restrict running and uploading rdl file in a site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, reporting-services

I want to restrict uploading and running rdl file and rsds file in a site collection. More clearly, I don't let user to add/upload or run rdl file in a SharePoint site collection.

How can I do that?
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is one setting in sharepoint called blocked file type, you can block it for entire farm or at a single web application.

If you add the rdl in block file type then no body can upload it.

you can not do this at site collection level.

Read more here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287701(v=office.14).aspx

But there is 3rd party code plex solution which can do at document library level. Check this

https://sharepoint247.wordpress.com/2013/06/01/block-file-types-for-a-document-library-in-sharepoint-website/

Comment: Hi
I know how to block from farm or web app level BUT I need to do it in site collection level.

Comment: That's not possible at site collection level, but there is code plex solution for it.check updated answer